# Why I cant perform soft delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, soft-delete

I want to flag character to false in DB and retrieve the true ones.
this is what I did I declare `bool IsDeleted { get; set; } = true`

character service

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDto>>> sDeleteCharacter(int id)
    {
        ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDto>> response = new ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDto>>();

       
            Character character = await _context.Characters
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == id && c.User.Id == GetUserId());
            if (character != null)
            {
               character.IsDeleted = false ;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

             response.Data = _context.Characters
                    .Where(c => c.User.Id == GetUserId()) 
                    .Select(c => _mapper.Map<GetCharacterDto>(c)).ToList();
            }
```

`GetAll` method where I specify the character that I want to retrieve based on `IsDelete` value

```
    public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDto>>> GetAllCharacters()
    {
        var response = new ServiceResponse<List<GetCharacterDto>>();
        var dbCharacters = await _context.Characters
            
      .Where(c => c.User.Id == GetUserId() && c.IsDeleted== true)
            .ToListAsync(); 
        response.Data = dbCharacters.Select(c => _mapper.Map<GetCharacterDto>(c)).ToList();
        return response;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: SoftDelete @riffnl

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: You need to specify what happens and what you expected to happen. If you mean to delete the character in `sDeleteCharacter`, you probably shouldn't set `IsDeleted` to false.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem - just override the savechanges()

```
using System;

namespace SoftDeleted.Models
{
    public interface ISoftDeleted
        
    {

        bool IsDeleted { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

DB

```
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            
        }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasQueryFilter(b => !b.IsDeleted);
}
public override int SaveChanges() 
  {
    HandleEmployeeDelete();
    return base.SaveChanges();
  }
  private void HandleEmployeeDelete() 
  {
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
    foreach(var entity in entities) 
    {
      if (entity.Entity is Employee) 
      {
        entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
        var c= entity.Entity as Employee;
        c.IsDeleted = true;
      }
    }
  }

            


   public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
     
                   
    }
}
```